# Return if empty in jquery is not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using an autocomplete jquery script. the searching is working perfectly but the part where if the search is empty it should display a message is not working.

Here's my autocomplete code from my controller,

```
public function transferResponse(Request $request){
    $query = $request->get('term','');
    $wh1Summaries=Warehouse1StockSummaries::with('product');

    if($request->type == 'product_code'){
        $wh1Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    if($request->type=='product_name'){
        $wh1Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    if($request->type=='qty_in'){
        $wh1Summaries->where('qty_in','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    }

    if($request->type=='product_id'){
        $wh1Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    $wh1Summaries=$wh1Summaries->get();        
    $data=array();
    foreach ($wh1Summaries as $wh1Summary) {
        $data[]=array(
            'product_code'=>$wh1Summary->product->product_code,
            'name'=>$wh1Summary->product->name,
            'qty_in'=>$wh1Summary->qty_in,
            'qty_out'=>$wh1Summary->qty_in-$wh1Summary->qty_out,
            'id'=>$wh1Summary->product->id
        );
    }
    if(count($data))
        return $data;
    else
        return [
            'product_code'=>'Code not found!'
        ];        
}
```

if the user type invalid code, here's what looks like

[image]

it should display the "Code not found!"

**UPDATE**

AUTOCOMPLETE script

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
  type = $(this).data('type');

  if(type =='product_code' )autoType='product_code'; 
  if(type =='product_name' )autoType='name'; 

   $(this).autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchStock') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    type : type,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                       return {
                           label: item[autoType],
                           value: item[autoType],
                           data : item
                       }
                   });
                    response(array)
                }
            });
        },

        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var data = ui.item.data; 
          var arr = []; 

          id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
          id = id_arr.split("_");
          elementId = id[id.length-1];

          $('.product_code').each(function() {
            arr.push($(this).val());
          });

          // added logic to check if there are duplicates in the array we just populated with product codes, checked against the passed in product code 
          if(arr.includes(data.product_code)) {
              $('#add').prop('disabled', true);
              $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
              $('#row'+rowCount+'').addClass('danger');
              // $('#duplicate_entry_'+elementId).text('Duplicate entry. Replace product code to continue. ');
              alert('Duplicate entry. Replace product code to continue. ');
          } else {
              $('#add').prop('disabled', false);
              $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
              $('#row'+rowCount+'').removeClass('danger');

              $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
              $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
              $('#qty_in_'+elementId).val(data.qty_in);
              $('#qty_out_'+elementId).val(data.qty_out).prop('max', data.qty_out);;
              $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
              $('#qty_out_warning_'+elementId).text('You have '+data.qty_out+' items in your stocks');     
          }
        }
   });
});
```

can you help me please? thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you return the same structure on failure that you return on success? however... there's probably a better way to handle this than to have your select populated with an invalid selectable option.

Comment: are you sure that else statement works in that situation?

Comment: hi @KevinB apology I forgot the script. I just updated my question